# Bulk Insert From Select

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2012, bulkinsert

I have a text file with about 300 million lines in it. I am doing a bulk insert to get the file into a staging table in sql. I then break out some columns to normalize it which works fine and quick. The last step I do is move the rows from the staging table to their final table. Currently I am doing a INSERT INTO SELECT statement but it is taking forever. Is there a way to do a bulk insert from a select?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Import/Export wizard provided by SQL Server Management Studio.

http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/203/simple-way-to-import-data-into-sql-server/

It will generate and run SSIS package for you which is much faster and better then INSERT INTO SELECT statement.

Comment: I have used SSIS for this process. It was very efficient to get the raw data into the database but once in there, it needed to be normalized. The bottleneck is moving the data from the staging table to the final normalized table.

Comment: @user2120910 SSIS is efficient in all sort of transformations, but simplest solution - if you already have a select statement from stage you can use for insert - just use that Select as your SSIS source and have a package transfer that data without any transformations.

Comment: I've tried that as well, seems to yield the same results. My insert time is about 45 minutes for 30 million rows. I was able to reduce it from 51 minutes by disabling the indexes before the insert and rebuild them afterwards. Perhaps this is as quick as it gets?

Comment: Perhaps it is, it depends a also o your number and size of columns and a lot on your hardware, especially hard disk. It would help if your source and target are on different disks if that's possible. Good thinking with disabling indexes. Check this link for some more speed-up hints http://svangasql.wordpress.com/2012/04/10/simple-tips-to-speed-up-your-ssis-data-flow/

Answer (score -1):

You can add parallel hints to the INSERT.

See for some more options. Like making sure to disable any indexes on target table
http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_insert_tuning.htm

Most importantly you can actually make this table a EXTERNAL table. This will be a particularly best suited to your specification.

Example Syntax:

```
create table xtern_empl_rpt
    ( empl_id varchar2(3),
      last_name varchar2(50),
      first_name varchar2(50),
      ssn varchar2(9),
     email_addr varchar2(100),
      years_of_service number(2,0)
    )
    organization external
```

This way then coupled with the parallel hint should speed up your DML.

```
insert /*+ parallel */ into tb_b t 
select * from xtern_empl_rpt where <<whatever predicate required>>
```

Source: http://www.orafaq.com/node/848

Comment: The question should have the database tagged on it.  However, it mentions "select into" to create a new table.  In Oracle, the syntax is "create table as".  My guess is the database is SQL Server, Sybase, Postgres, or a Postgres-based database.

Comment: Good point. I assumed Oracle. My bad. Perhaps the word BULK got me thinking that way. However your point about it mentions "select into" i didnt quite see in the original post??